# unexpected end_of_file when using read/1

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to read from a text file,
when I use `get\1`

```
see('test.txt'),get(X).
```

I get the right matching,

```
X= 104
```

(hello. is the only word in the text file)

But when I use

```
see('test.txt'),read(X).
```

I get

```
Error 43 : End Of File.
```

why?

According to the book I'm learning from it should match X to the term in the file.

Comment: `read` aims to parse a Prolog expression that ends with a `.`

Comment: Note: see/1 and get/1 are old and not used with modern Prolog. The book is dated, not your fault. See: [Edinburgh-style I/O](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=edinburghIO) which is part of SWI-Prolog [Input and output](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=IO).

Answer (score 0):

[**`read/1`** [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=read/1) will parse a Prolog *term*:

> Read the **next Prolog term** from the current input stream and unify it with `Term`. On a syntax error `read/1` displays an error message, attempts to skip the erroneous term and fails. On reaching end-of-file Term is unified with the atom `end_of_file`.

Such Prolog term ends with a dot (`.`). So if your file contains:

```
104.
```

then it will parse it and bind `X` with `104`. If the file contains:

```
f(Y, Z).
```

it will unify `X` with `f(_m, _n)` (`m` and `n` are numbers here, and `_m` and `_n` are thus variables).

But it thus needs a dot to mark the end of the term.

[**`get/1`** [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=get/1) reads a single character, and unifies the variable with the character code (and unifies with `-1` in case the stream has ended).